# How to define the suggestion area in a AutoSuggestBox for Windows 10?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

Is it possible to define the size of the suggestion area for an AutoSuggestBox  for Windows 10 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
   var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(AutoSuggestBox, 0) as Grid;
           var border = grid?.FindName("SuggestionsContainer") as Border;
           if (border != null)
           {
              var height = border.ActualHeight;
              Debug.WriteLine(height);
           }
```